# Plus sign isn't read

Tags: c, switch-statement, ascii

For some reason my program doesn't read plus sign at all and it doesn't matter if I do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (){

 int nextInt,number,boolean;
 char sign;
 scanf("%d", &number);
 boolean = 1;

 while(boolean == 1){ //+43 *42 %37
   scanf("%c %d", &sign, &nextInt);

   switch ((int)sign){
     case 43:{ number += nextInt; printf("+= %d\n", number); break;}
     case 42:{ number *= nextInt; printf("*= %d\n", number); break;}
     case 37:{ printf("mod %d\n", number);
                number %= nextInt;
                boolean = 0; break;}
   }
 }

 printf("%d", number);
 return 0;
}
```

Or switch ascii with symbols for switch (sign). I'm kinda clueless what is really the source of the problem right now. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Entire code pasted

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: In `scanf("%c %d", &sign, &nextInt);` don't mix these types in a loop easily. You need a `space` before the `%c`, as in `scanf(" %c %d", &sign, &nextInt);`. This cleans off whitespace (such as the `newline` left in the previous loop).

Comment: Wow. A space before %c actually works like a charm. It's interesting how only a plus sign has this issue. Why does it work like this?

Comment: You can use character literals in `switch` statements, and doing so makes things *a lot* more readable. For example: `switch (sign) { case '+': ...; case '*': ...; }

Comment: Yes I did that but I thought I was doing something wrong with the apostrophe or something. So I've decided to parse char into int but it still didn't work

Comment: @Sjal, it depends on the sequence. In the first loop it won't matter, since there was no previous input. On subsequent loops, there remains a `newline` in the input buffer. Perhaps it was "finger trouble" in your testing.

Comment: He means `case 43:` --> `case '+':`

Answer (score 0):

Since 1806 % 37 = 30, you can verify that the following works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

  int nextInt=0;
  int number=0;
  int boolean;
  char sign;
  boolean = 1;

  while(boolean == 1){ //+43 *42 %37
    scanf(" %c %d", &sign, &nextInt);

    switch (sign){
      case '+':{ number += nextInt; printf("+= %d\n", number); break;}
      case '*':{ number *= nextInt; printf("*= %d\n", number); break;}
      case '%':{ printf("mod %d\n", number);
        number %= nextInt;
        boolean = 0; break;}
    }
  }

  printf("%d", number);
  return 0;
}
```

The reason your program didn't read plus is that it wasn't in the loop. You can verify that the program works:

```
+43
+= 43
*42
*= 1806
%37
mod 1806
30
Process finished with exit code 0
```